# python subprocess module gives command not found error if order of command is differerent

Tags: linux, python-2.7, subprocess

I have this code in which i'm using subprocess module to do ssh and run some commands and get the response.

```
command = "ssh -n " +str(server_name) + " sudo /etc/init.d/postfix status && sudo /etc/init.d/ssh status && sudo /etc/init.d/lldpd status"
result = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
response, err = result.communicate()
print response
```

it returns

```
sudo: /etc/init.d/lldpd: command not found
```

but if i format command like this

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lldpd status && sudo /etc/init.d/postfix status && sudo /etc/init.d/ssh status
```

it works perfectly.it won't work if i put lldpd into other than first position in command.
i can run the command on server in any order and it's working.

Edit:-
for this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix status  && sudo /etc/init.d/ssh status && sudo /etc/init.d/lldpd status
```

i have this output

```
sudo: /etc/init.d/lldpd: command not found
postfix is running.
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-05-28 14:13:49 IST; 19h ago
Process: 20365 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 651 (sshd)
CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
       └─651 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

May 29 09:36:33 rohit systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit sshd[651]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit sshd[651]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit sshd[651]: Server listening on :: port 22.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit sshd[651]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit sshd[651]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit sshd[651]: Server listening on :: port 22.
```

for this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lldpd status && sudo /etc/init.d/postfix status  && sudo /etc/init.d/ssh status
```

i have this output

```
lldpd is running.
● postfix.service - LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/postfix)
Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/postfix.service.d
       └─50-postfix-$mail-transport-agent.conf
Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-05-28 14:14:10 IST; 19h ago
Process: 20381 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/postfix reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 1350 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/postfix start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
       ├─ 1474 /usr/lib/postfix/master
       ├─20395 pickup -l -t unix -u -c
       └─20396 qmgr -l -t unix -u

May 29 08:33:43 rohit systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
May 29 08:33:43 rohit postfix[18121]: Reloading Postfix configuration...done.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit postfix/master[1474]: reload -- version 2.11.3, configuration /etc/postfix
May 29 09:36:33 rohit postfix[20292]: Reloading Postfix configuration...done.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit postfix/master[1474]: reload -- version 2.11.3, configuration /etc/postfix
May 29 09:36:33 rohit postfix[20381]: Reloading Postfix configuration...done.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-05-28 14:13:49 IST; 19h ago
Process: 20365 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 651 (sshd)
CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
       └─651 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

May 29 09:36:33 rohit systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit sshd[651]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit sshd[651]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit sshd[651]: Server listening on :: port 22.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit sshd[651]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit sshd[651]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
May 29 09:36:33 rohit sshd[651]: Server listening on :: port 22.
```

Comment: I think only the first command gets run remotely because the shell splits the command line on `&&`. For example, as the 3 commands `ssh -n servername /etc/init.d/lldpd status` and `sudo /etc/init.d/postfix status` and `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh status`. In which case maybe you don't have a local `/etc/init.d/lldpd` file when it's reordered.

Comment: @eryksun not sure if i understand you explanation.i have included output of both scenario in edits.

Comment: When you run the command via `shell=True`, it's actually running it as `['/bin/sh', '-c', command]`, and the shell will split `command` into 3 commands separated by the `&&` operator. Then, if that's the case, only the first command is run remotely, for example `ssh -n servername sudo /etc/init.d/lldpd status`.

Comment: @eryksun so is there any workaround this ?

Comment: Try passing the ssh command line in single quotes, e.g. `" 'sudo /etc/init.d/postfix status && sudo /etc/init.d/ssh status && sudo /etc/init.d/lldpd status'"`.

Comment: @eryksun This works .Thanks